# How to replace xml element from looping list on python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have a xml tree and I would like to replace the sub elements in the xml structure.
This is actual xml tree read from the file

xml_data = ET.parse('file1.xml')

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<call method="xxxx" callerName="xxx">  
<credentials login="" password=""/>
<filters>
<accounts>
<account code="" ass="" can=""/>
</accounts>
</filters>
</call>
```

I'm expecting this format from looping the list

```
a = [1,23453, 3543,4354,3455, 6345]

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<call method="xxxx" callerName="xxx">  
<credentials login="" password=""/>
<filters>
<accounts>
<account code="1" ass="34" can="yes"/>
<account code="23453" ass="34" can="yes"/>
<account code="3543" ass="34" can="yes"/>
<account code="4354" ass="34" can="yes"/>
<account code="3455" ass="34" can="yes"/>
<account code="6345" ass="34" can="yes"/>
</accounts>
</filters>
</call>
```

New to xml-parsing. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new in python, but it's work. I find only 1 bug: len of a must be equal len . It would be great if i help you. Good luck.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

a = [1, 23453, 3543, 4354, 3455, 6345]
code = 0
xmlfile = "./log/logs.xml"
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()
for filters in root.findall("filters"):
    for accounts in filters.findall("accounts"):
        for account in accounts.findall("account"):
            attributes = account.attrib
            attributes["code"] = str(a[code])
            attributes["ass"] = "34"
            attributes["can"] = "yes"
            code += 1
tree.write(xmlfile)
```